# All user SocialAuth detail fields from Facebook are null

Tags: django-socialauth, python-social-auth, socialauth, spring-social-facebook

I am not getting any data except fullname and profile-imageurl. I am trying to get details from my Facebook account. And I make email, date-of-birth public. Even, I am not getting any details.

In propeties file:

```
facebook  
graph.facebook.com.consumer_key=6456435634
graph.facebook.com.consumer_secret=twretwert45645624ghtgfdbgfd        
graph.facebook.com.custom_permissions=public_profile,publish_actions,email,user_birthday,user_location,user_photos,user_friends
```

In other api's I found some thing like **_USER_FIELDS** which allow to specify the list of fields needed. But in SocialAuth, I did not found any thing like that.

In my Controller:

```
private ModelAndView registration(final AuthProvider provider)
        throws Exception {
    Profile profile = provider.getUserProfile();
    if (profile.getFullName() == null) {
        String name = null;

    ......
}
```

**profile object data:**

```
org.brickred.socialauth.Profile Object {
 email: null
 firstName: null
 lastName: null
 country: null
 language: null
 fullName: Kumar Guru
 displayName: null
 dob: null
 gender: null
 location: null
 validatedId: 4335634576457
 profileImageURL: http://graph.facebook.com/664564356234/picture
 providerId: facebook
 contactInfo { 
 } 
}
```